# How can I know if a std::string was actually created?

Tags: c++, out-of-memory, stdstring

I want to use the `std::string(size_type count,CharT ch)` with a big value for `count`. Reading https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/basic_string, I could not find an exception definition for this constructor, in case it fails.

If it is correct, although there is not a `noexcept` clause in the constructor, how can I be sure that the string was created? Should I check if its size is not 0?

Comment: The `basic_string` template uses the allocator to allocate memory, and by default it's the [`std::allocator`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/allocator) template, whose [`allocate`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/allocator/allocate) member function can throw [`std::bad_alloc`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/new/bad_alloc) on failure.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your link says it under *Exceptions*:

> Throws std::length_error if the length of the constructed string would exceed max_size() (for example, if count > max_size() for (2)). Calls to Allocator::allocate may throw.

Also `std::string` uses an allocator which means `std::bad_alloc` can be thrown aswell, if the allocator fails to allocate the requested amount of memory.

Comment: I'd also mention `std::bad_alloc`.

Comment: @canellas Consider accepting this answer to remove your question from the list off unanswered questions.